# Gradlew and Java 9 in Cmd :FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, gradlew, minecraft-forge

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This is displayed when I'm running in the console (Cmd) :

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

My gradlewrapper-properties are:

```
#Wed Jul 02 15:54:47 CDT 2014 
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
distributionPath=wrapper/dists 
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip
```

The problem is clearly Java 9 but I do not know what to do to solve it.
Install Java X.X.X or reinstall Java?

Comment: Which gradle version are you using? Check gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties or `gradlew --version`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using gradle 2.0, but support for Java 9 in gradle requires at least gradle 3, and the latest gradle version at the moment is 4.7.

Normally, you would be able to upgrade your gradle wrapper using

```
gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.7
```

But given your current version of the wrapper (2.0) doesn't support Java 9, this won't work.

As a workaround, you'll need to install gradle so you can use that to upgrade the wrapper. Follow the instructions on https://gradle.org/install/

Then - assuming gradle is configured on the `PATH` - use in the root of your project:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7
```

(notice the use of `gradle` not `gradlew`)

If gradle isn't on the `PATH` use

```
<path-to-your-gradle-install>\bin\gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.7
```

Afterwards, you can consider to remove/uninstall the gradle installation again.

Comment: I'm doing this in the cmd ?

Comment: Yes, in the root folder of your project

Comment: @Taupeman Sorry, my mistake. This is a bit of a chicken and egg problem. You can't use the wrappers own upgrade mechanism, because the current version you're using does not support Java 9. Let me see what the easiest way is to address that.

Comment: Hum, so, gradle is installed but I have a other error. So thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try making this simple change to the gradle-wrapper.properties file

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip